# Tem como recuperar quais PDOStatement no PDO PHP foram criado?

Tags: php, pdo

Vejam só, eu utilizo o PDO no PHP para executar minhas Querys, acontece as vezes uso a mesma query em outras janelas e então preciso montar novamente a mesma Query na outra página.
O que tenho em mente:

Quero guardar o select numa session para reutilizar na proxima página, assim tenho certeza de que estou usando a mesma query (pra trazer o mesmo resultado) e evito redigitação o que poderia me levar a erros.

Então tenho:

```
$SQL = "select * from tabela where (codcli = :codcli) and (pedido in(:codigos)))";

$Query = Database::Prepare($SQL);
$Query->bindValue(":codcli", "234");
$Query->bindValue(":codigos", "1,2,4,6,7,8");
$Query->Execute();

Eu consigo guardar o $SQL

$_SESSION["SQL_TEXT"] = $SQL;
```

Tem uma forma de pegar quais PDOStatement (bindValue) foram criados e seus respectivos valores?

Eu tentei dar um var_dump em $Query->bindValue() mas sem sucesso, na Query ele só mostra o texto

Eu querys dar um foreach no binvValue pra guardar os paremetros e seus devidos valores

```
$parametros = array();

    foreach ($Query->bindValue as $key=>$value){
      $parametros[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível a partir da versão 7.2, visualizar as informações contidas em uma instrução que foi montada no `$dbh->prepare` que prepara uma instrução SQL a ser executada pelo método `PDOStatement::execute()`.

Sobre `PDOStatement::debugDumpParams`: responsável por despejar um comando  SQL - Ele fornecerá a consulta SQL em uso, o número de parâmetros usados ​​(Params), a lista de parâmetros com seu nome ou posição de chave, seu nome, sua posição na consulta (se isso for suportado pelo driver PDO, caso contrário, será -1)

Um exemplo retirado da documentação PHP, porém sem a saída completamente formatada com os valores(Sent SQL), parâmetros... Veja:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();

$sth->debugDumpParams();

?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
SQL: [96] SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour
Params:  2
Key: Name: [9] :calories
paramno=-1
name=[9] ":calories"
is_param=1
param_type=1
Key: Name: [7] :colour
paramno=-1
name=[7] ":colour"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

A partir da versão 7.2, agora retorna o SQL enviado ao banco de dados, você visualiza onde contém **Sent SQL**:

```
...
$sth->bindValue(':campo', "Um valor qualquer", PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
$sth->debugDumpParams();
```

**Saída** do *$sth->debugDumpParams()*:

```
SQL: [60] SELECT campo
    FROM  tabela
    WHERE campo LIKE :campo
Sent SQL: [79] SELECT campo
    FROM  tabela
    WHERE campo LIKE 'Um valor qualquer'
Params:  1
Key: Name: [5] :campo
paramno=-1
name=[5] ":campo"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Observe que isso só estará disponível se as "emulated prepared statements"(https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718418/3658278) estiverem ativadas.

No seu caso teríamos que usar uma expressão regular ou outra forma para pegar o valor que começa a partir do ***Sent SQL:***. Sabendo que `public PDOStatement::debugDumpParams(void):void` não retorna nada, pois o resultado é enviado diretamente para o navegador, então é preciso ativar o **buffer de saída** (ob_start()) para capturar a saída dessa função e salvá-la em uma string. Daí sim realizar o tratamento e recuperar o trecho referente ao comando SQL final.

**Veja:**

```
$SQL = "select * from tabela where (codcli = :codcli) and (pedido in(:codigos)))";

$Query = Database::Prepare($SQL);
$Query->bindValue(":codcli", "234");
$Query->bindValue(":codigos", "1,2,4,6,7,8");
$Query->Execute();


ob_start();
$Query->debugDumpParams();
$conteudo = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


$iniciaEm = strpos($conteudo, "Sent SQL:") + strlen("Sent SQL:");
$finalizaEm = strpos($conteudo, "Params:", $iniciaEm);
$resultadoParcial = substr($conteudo, $iniciaEm, $finalizaEm - $iniciaEm);

$res = preg_replace("/[][0-9]/", "", $resultadoParcial );

//Aqui está sua SQL...
//$_SESSION["SQL_TEXT"] = $res;
echo $res;
```

Viu como é possível? Porém, isso num projeto em produção é preciso ficar atento para possíveis mudanças em versões futuras, como uma simples mudança na saída do texto "Sent SQL" para qualquer outro texto.

Comment: Show, me deu uma boa pista do que eu precisava.